# Querying CSV's on Azure Serverless SQL pool results in a cryptic error message

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have some CSV's in my Storage blob that I am trying to create a query on. Even a simple select statement causes a lot of issues, and seemingly weird is that with the SELECT statement TOP(10) works but if remove the top statement it doesn't, I am new to Azure and could make head and toes of the error message.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
   OPENROWSET(BULK 'Navision_SQL/....', ---change path
   FORMAT = 'CSV', 
   PARSER_VERSION = '2.0', 
   HEADER_ROW = TRUE,
   DATA_SOURCE = '', --fill 
   ROWSET_OPTIONS = '{"READ_OPTIONS":["ALLOW_INCONSISTENT_READS"] }') 
AS SLHS
GO
```

Statement ID: {4B7B1DDD-B849-4E1F-A673-08114E5C9EB0} | Query hash: 0x876820D2CCD0F04F | Distributed request ID: {3DE169A8-1082-4B28-A074-26B0781448FE}. Total size of data scanned is 460 megabytes, total size of data moved is 56 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.
Msg 19733, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

I tried googling the error message with no results

Comment: The above shown error message is the same it is showing or it is missing few lines after `State 1, Line 1`

Comment: @Balaji Could you explain a little bit more? I am not sure what that error code means, all I am doing is a simple select statement.

Comment: Is the error message is showing upto `State 1, Line 1` or anything more after `State 1, Line1` ?

Comment: As far as I can tell only upto State 1, Line 1

Comment: Ok, I tried from my end in Azure Synapse Studio and it got executed [successfully](https://i.imgur.com/WeGNegr.png)

Comment: Without the error message, it is not possible to troubleshoot the issue. Hide the confidential details (replace them with `xxxx`) and share the debugging details.

Comment: This was found that in Azure querying CSV with text columns that contain ',' character was the reason for this error. If I remove that column when copying it doesnt throw the same error. We switch to parquet as a solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error causes because of the text columns that contains with  `,`  in  `.csv` file. So, instead of using `.csv` it is better to use `.parquet` format, it is a good choice for storing and processing large amounts of data in Azure. By using `.parquet` format the issues caused by `.csv` file can be resolved. I tried from my end, it executed successfully. A sample `.parquert` file path is given in the query as you can see below:

```sql
select top 10 *
from openrowset
(
    bulk '<.parquet file path>',
    format = 'parquet'
) as rows
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Balaji, on a similar note, could you guide me to a resource where I can automate the replacement of special characters in the field names so parquet accepts the data copy? I have >20000 tables, so manually changing field names is not an option.